# Adding UIBarButtonItem to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibarbuttonitem

I have modified my project to use a UIScrollView with UIPageControl at the bottom of my app.  Initially my view included just a UIWebView and on the right side of the toolbar I had a UIButtonBarItem.  When I switched to the Scrollview my UIButtonBarItem no longer appears.  I am sure that I am missing a simple concept here with the two.

Comment: Are you using UIButtonBarItem to go back from scrollview to your UIWebView. ?

Comment: No I am trying to add a UIBarButtonSystemItemAction to allow sharing on social networks. My ScrollView contains the UIWebView I was using before the change.  I simply added a Scrollview that will allow me to scroll through the various stories without having to go back to the Listview.  The Back button is still visible and works.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured out part of the problem but still need help.  The UINavigationBar is attached to the ScrollView and not the ViewController loaded inside the scrollview.  How do I assign the UINavigationBar to each individual view inside the ScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem by adding the sharing button and code to the ScrollView Controller instead of the ViewController inside the ScrollView.  It is probably not ideal since it requires the ScrollView to have more knowledge of the contained view but it is a solution for now.